# Jquery parameter in id check [id=...]

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the checkbox with the ids: checkbox0, checkbox1, checkbox2, ... but can't seem to find how to give parameters to the second line.

```
for (var i = 0; i < @Model.ProjectCategories.Count; i++) {                
            $('input:checkbox[id="checkbox" + i]').change(
            function () {
                alert(this);
                if (this.is(':checked')) {                                                                                                          
                    $('#maakproject_' + this.id.charAt(this.id.length -     1)).show();
                } else {                       
                    $('#maakproject_' + this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1)).hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: please share your html code with us

Comment: i would have shared it if it was of any need, i just need to know how to pass the parameter "i" in the 2nd line

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the id selector? `#theId`?

Comment: yeah, i tried it before but didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :You have to concatenate `i` with checkbox. Use same for `maakproject` with `i`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < @Model.ProjectCategories.Count; i++) {                
            $('input:checkbox[id="checkbox"' + i +']').change(
            function () {
                alert($(this));
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {                                                                                                          
                    $('#maakproject_' + i).show();
                } else {                       
                    $('#maakproject_' + i).hide();
                }
            });
```

Instead of running loop i would suggest to use jquery start with selector. If your checkbox count varies then you don't have to touch the script again. See below script

```
$(function(){
  //bind change event handler using start with selector i.e. checkbox id starting with checkbox
  $('input[id^="checkbox"]').change(function(){
     //get index from checkbox id
     var checkboxIndex = $(this).attr('id').replace('checkbox','');
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
       $('#maakproject_'+checkboxIndex).show();
     }
     else
     {
       $('#maakproject_'+checkboxIndex).hide();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: doesn't go into the change function :s

Comment: have you put your code inside `$(function(){...});` block as shown in my second solution. Or try with my second solution.

Comment: it won't go into the if, so i think $(this) doesn't have an attribute checked?

Comment: scrap that, you removed the _ from maakproject and i didn't notice! Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry my bad. Actually `this` is DOM object and don't have `is(':checked')`. Try with `$(this)` (updated in my answer, added `_` in maakproject)

Comment: in case you didn't read my comments i just posted, thank you! :)
1 thing, it has to be show in the if :p

Comment: yeah, you added comments but not refreshed at my side hence could not see it. my bad. Anyways happy to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to concatenate the string:

`$('input:checkbox[id="checkbox"' + i + ']').change(...`

However you would be better served just using an id selector:

`$('#checkbox' + i).change(...`

Or better yet, assign a common attribute (say a class name) and use:

`$('.myClassName').change(...`

Comment: Well, you didn't post all the relevant information. What do you expect? The last portion of the answer is basically exactly the same as the accepted answer. Assign a common attribute and use a single query to find the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This will list all input filed starts with name "checkbox":

```
$("input[id^='checkbox']").each(function() { 
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: i have to check it on id, but doesn't work even if i change your code